# How can I get the area of each Voronoi Polygon in R?

Tags: r, polygon, area

I have a set of coordinates X and Y for my points and used the `deldir` to create determine and plot the Voronoi Polygons. (I've used this tutorial [here](http://flowingdata.com/2016/04/12/voronoi-diagram-and-delaunay-triangulation-in-r/))

This is my plot: (sorry that its so small, but you get the idea).
[image]

I need to determine the area of each polygon. How can I do that?
I looked up in the `deldir`package page and couldnt find anything related to the Voronoi polygons, only about other

Comment: Does this help? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonArea.html

Comment: The `pracma` package has a function called `polyarea` that will do what you want.

Comment: @HongOoi I did not have the coordinates of the vertices of the polygons, only the center point (which isnt technically 'center').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the reference manual (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deldir/index.html), the output of the `deldir` function is a list. One of the list element, `summary`, is a data frame, which contains a column called `dir.area`. This is the ***the area of the Dirichlet tile surrounding the point***, which could be what you are looking for.

Below I am using the example from the reference manual. Use `$` to access the `summary` data frame.

```
library(deldir)

x <- c(2.3,3.0,7.0,1.0,3.0,8.0)
y <- c(2.3,3.0,2.0,5.0,8.0,9.0)

dxy1 <- deldir(x,y)

dxy1$summary
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it does work as intended. I didnt know "Dirichlet tiles" was a synonim for "Voronoi Polygons" (wikipedia confirmed that). 

It was easier than I thought.